# I am getting "During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version" error while deploying my app

Tags: amazon-web-services, springboot, amazon-codepipeline

I am getting **Action execution failed
Deployment completed, but with errors: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version. Failed to deploy application. Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0a956bec0b978125a'. Aborting the operation. [Instance: i-0a956bec0b978125a] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error.. Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.**  error while deploying via code pipeline.

I have no idea why this error occurring. My application is a legacy spring 1.5.9 application built on java 8.

My buildspec.yml:

```
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto8
  build:
    commands:
      - java -version
      - mvn clean install
artifacts:
  files:
    - target/d_campus.jar
```

Its about 4 hours.....I am stucked. Please help

Comment: I am facing the same problem Deployment completed, but with errors: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version. Failed to deploy application. Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-04ef0b651fcb9aab8'. Aborting the operation. [Instance: i-04ef0b651fcb9aab8] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error.. Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.